# Syntax error in print function

Tags: python, xml, csv, syntax

I'm getting this from a script that converts csv to xml

syntax error invalid syntax

```
print(text, file=self.file, end=self.args.linebreak)
```

the point is under the first "=". I'm not sure why this is. Can someone point in the right direction.

Thanks
Alonzo

```
class Writer:
def __init__(self, ofile, args):
    self.file = ofile
    self.args = args
    self.newline_subst = field_subst_factory(args.newline_elem)
    if args.header:
        self.fieldname = self.__fieldname_header
    elif args.flat_fields:
        self.fieldname = self.__fieldname_flat
    else:
        self.fieldname = self.__fieldname_indexed
def write_file(self, data):
    if self.args.declaration:
        declaration = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{0}"?>'.
                       format(args.oencoding))
        self.write(declaration)
    self.write("<{0}>".format(self.args.root_elem))
    for record in data:
        self.write_record(record)
    self.write("<\{0}>".format(self.args.root_elem))
def write_record(self, record):
    self.write("{0}<{1}>".
               format(self.args.indent, self.args.record_elem))
    for index, field in enumerate(record):
        self.write_field(field, index)
    self.write("{0}<\{1}>".
               format(self.args.indent, self.args.record_elem))
def write_field(self, field, index):
    self.write("{0}{0}<{1}>{2}</{1}>".
               format(self.args.indent, self.fieldname(index),
                      self.newline_subst(field)))
def write(self, text):
    **print(text, file=self.file, end=self.args.linebreak)** This the line that's causing issues
def __fieldname_header(self, index):
    return self.args.header[index]
def __fieldname_flat(self, index):
    return self.args.field_elem
def __fieldname_indexed(self, index):
    return self.args.field_elem + str(index)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python version 3

Comment: That line compiles fine for me. It could be the result of something further back in the code, so posting a bit more of the code would help.

Comment: The entire source file compiles fine for me in Python 3.3.1, but fails in Python 2.7.4 with the error you mentioned. Are you sure you're running it with version 3.x? Is there perhaps a shebang line at the top of the file like `#!/usr/bin/env python` causing it to run in version 2.x?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python 2.x then you need to put the following line at the top of your code

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using version 3

Comment: Stephen, maybe I'm wrong but to my understanding the carrot pointing to the first "=" means that the character preceding the "=" is the issue. Or am I misunderstanding phtyon documentation?

Comment: self.write("{0}{0}<{1}>{2}</{1}>".
                   format(self.args.indent, self.fieldname(index),
                          self.newline_subst(field)))
    def write(self, text):
        print(text, file=self.file, end=self.args.linebreak)

Comment: Soory but I try to oad my code the site stripes the formating and in just comes across as a block of text

Comment: there we go I think I have it figured now

Comment: try passing file as a parameter to the function instead of accessing it through self @user2533054

Comment: do you mean file=path/to/file versus the self.file?

Comment: @user2533054 no, i mean  where it says write(self, text) make it say write(self, text, file) and then just say file=file

Comment: last try: post the whole error message in the question please @user2533054

Comment: File "csv2xml.py", line 208
    print(text, file=self.file, end=self.args.linebreak)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax the ^ is under the first "="

Comment: @user2533054 try switching to file.write() instead of print()